# How to Convert 20,000 Lumens to Lux?

Tags: led, light, watts

I need to generate 20,000 lux of light in an indoor environment. I am having trouble converting the lumens to lux using online converters ( I know there are many such converters but the questions they ask are ambiguous).

Here is my situation:

I will have 25 light bulbs in a straight line above my head. Each light bulb will emit 800 lumens of light. The light bulbs will be 3 ft above my head. They will span around 5 feet in length. In other words, some light bulbs will be directly above my head, some will be a little to the right and others will be a little to the left.

How can I calculate the amount of lux that will hit my eyes?

What makes things further complex is that the light is radiating from all sides of the bulb (I'm talking about standard bulbs) so it is difficult to know how much light will radiate downward (in my direction)..

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Why do you need 20,000 Lumens?

Comment: Experiment.. I guess your curious :)

Comment: I still don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lux):

> The lux (symbol: lx) is ... equal to one lumen per square metre.

So there's your answer.  The biggest problem might be in keeping the two units straight, since they aren't well-known to most people.